# Function does not return correct value when a string is returned instead of null

Tags: javascript

I came across an example while studying. when I do a slight modification, it will not work

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if (current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
             find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

That is the example. But when I change the null in the else if statement to a string like in the example below. The else if statement is totally ignored. Example below

```
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(current, history) {
      if (current == target) {
        return history;
      } else if (current > target) {
         return "impossible";
      } else {
        return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
               find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);

      }
    }
    return find(1, "1");
  }

  console.log(findSolution(24));
```

In the above, the if else keeps running while ignoring the condition

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important part here is the `||`:

```
return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`) ||
       find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
```

The way `||` works, it will evaluate to the left side of the `||` *if* that left side is truthy. Otherwise, it'll evaluate to the right-hand side.

Here, if you return `'impossible'` instead of `null`, you're returning a non-empty string, which is truthy. As a result, the parent caller of `find` will return that truthy string, rather than going onto the alternation on the right-hand side.

To fix it, you could use `=== 'impossible'` instead:

```
if (left !== 'impossible') return left;
return find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
```

```js
function findSolution(target) {
    function find(current, history) {
      if (current == target) {
        return history;
      } else if (current > target) {
         return "impossible";
      } else {
        const left = find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5)`);
        if (left !== 'impossible') return left;
        return find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);

      }
    }
    return find(1, "1");
  }

  console.log(findSolution(24));
```